# 5G uplink switching from CP OFDM to DFT-s-OFDM

Tags: digital-communications, communication-standard

5g NR standards can allow for both CP-OFDM and DFT-s-OFDM in the uplink. Suppose a UE is allocated resources. Can the UE switch from CP-OFDM to DFT-s-OFDM from one slot to the next ? Are these possible in the same connection ( same PUSCH allocation) or does the UE have to send a PRACH and setup a new connection ?

Answer (score 2):

The term is *transform precoding*. Whether it is enabled is [configured semi-statically by RRC messages](https://www.sharetechnote.com/html/5G/5G_Waveform.html), which are usually broadcasted (periodically) in System information (SI) messages.

If the system information is still valid, UE does not automatically switch between the two modes. See [Subclause 5.2.2](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/138300_138399/138331/16.01.00_60/ts_138331v160100p.pdf) for the periodicity and validity of SI.

Differently put, the usage of the precoder is totally the choice of the network. Therefore, UE can be configured to switch mode without using PRACH to establish the new connection.